Intuitive Proof for AM-GM inequality
I wanted to know a general proof for AM-GM Inequality, without using some other complex inequalities, An Intuitive proof is what I want.
My Attempt:
I was hoping to prove it for small numbers and maybe afterwards I get a pattern by which I can prove it.
For 2 numbers:
$$\frac{x+y}{2}\geq xy$$
This was done by cross multiplying as it forms a perfect square.
But I couldn't do anything for more than 2 numbers.
Does an Intuitive proof for it exist?
(By Intuitive, I imply it may use some basic inequalities)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The shortest proofs use convex inequalities combined to $\exp,\ln$ are you familiar with these ? Else we can resort to prove it by induction, but it is a bit tedious.

@zwim No, I am not familiar with "convex inequalities"

There are about 10 proofs in Wikipedia: AM–GM inequality, is none of them “intuitive” enough for you?

Start with the following:
i. Let $a<1<b$:
Prove that:
$a+b>1+ab$
From which you can conclude that:
$a>0\rightarrow a+\frac{1}{a}\geq 2$
ii.
Let Let $n$ be a natural greater than 2.
And let:
$a_i>0, \;\forall 1\leq i\leq n$
and
$a_1*a_2...*a_n$=1
Show that:
$a_1+a_2+...+a_n\geq n$
When is there an equality?
iii.
Prove the AM-GM inequality from here.
I'll start you from i.:
$a+b>1+ab, \;a<1<b$
Since:
$a-ab+b=a+b(1-a)>a+1-a=1$
Since $b>1$.
This implies
$a+\frac{1}{a}\geq a+a\frac{1}{a}=2,\;a>0$
